# Or keyword in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I missing here? zipcode has a valid length but the if code has a red squiggly. This is always how i've used Or in jquery with the double pipes. If I enclose both conditions in parentheses then I get a blue squiggly that says the conditions are always true, how is that possible? What is wrong with this code syntax?

```
//testing here if its usa, if so run code below 
alert(zipcode.length);          
if (zipcode.length = 5 || zipcode.length = 9) {
    zip.addClass("isvalid");
    zip.css("border", "1px solid lightgray");
} else {                       
    zip.css("border", "2px solid red");
    alert("Invalid postal code entry, number is 5 or 9 digits");
    zip.focus();
}
```

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==`. Where's the duplicate?

Comment: Just to be clear, the `||`, `if` statements, `=`/`==`/`===`, and other fundamental pieces of the code are part of JavaScript, the language. jQuery is simply a *library* (not the language), written in JavaScript, that adds helpful objects and functions for use in JavaScript code.

Comment: duh...fatigue is the only explanation for that blunder, i always use ===

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (zipcode.length == 5 || zipcode.length == 9)
```

[Read here about operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your conditional again:

```
zipcode.length = 5 || zipcode.length = 9
```

`=` is the assignment operator, and the logical-or operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator, so the line evaluates the same as:

```
zipcode.length = (5 || zipcode.length) = 9
```

`5 || myvar` will evaluate to `5` in JavaScript, so you get

```
zipcode.length = 5 = 9
```

`9` **cannot** be assigned to `5`, so you get an error.

> If I enclose both conditions in parentheses then I get a blue squiggly that says the conditions are always true, how is that possible?

Consider the statement as they're evaluated:

```
(zipcode.length = 5) || (zipcode.length = 9)
5 || (zipcode.length = 9)
true || (zipcode.length = 9)
true
```

This is entirely aside from any problems that might be occurring if `zipcode` is a string vs. an array vs. some other kind of object, and  trying to set the `length` property on it!

All of this boils down to the real problem that `=` (assignment) is not the same operator as `==` or `===` (equality). If you simply add an additional equals sign to each side, you're suddenly *comparing* the zipcode's length to 5 and 9, instead of *setting* the zipcode's length.